# How to handle notifications in unfocused window?

Tags: notification

I'm having a radio website and whenever a new song comes up, it shows a notification and most of the time you don't have the window focused, so what to do if the user decides to click them?

- Hide Notification
- Hide Notification and focus window

Note that it is very hard to hit the "X" on the corner of the notification, so hiding it seems to be the best choice when the user wants it gone quickly.

Comment: Can you put some screenshots?

Comment: @Name Screenshots of what exactly? Isn't that description good enough?

Comment: How best to deal with this depends on the context and scenario. What are these notifications for? When might a user see one. How crucial are they to the primary task. Can you describe a scenario?

Comment: You are referring to some Window - what's the window exactly?

Comment: In addition to screenshots, clarification between what you consider an 'alert' and a 'notification' would need helpful - since the two do not have universally unique definitions.

Comment: @dennislees these are used to indicate the current song, sorry should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A notification like this should be passive, meaning it becomes visible as a secondary or tertiary UI element but doesn't force user interaction. You definitely don't want to make your users to close a notification every 3.5 minutes while they're on your site.

Think Outlook's tray notifications. Alternatively, you could ditch the notification concept all together and rely on the artist/song names changing to convey the point. If your users are listening they'll know when a song is over and another is beginning, so it kind of feels like an additional notification is overkill here.

Comment: I agree that song titles on a radio station need to be passive, meaning they should not interrupt the experience of using the radio to listen to the song.  I am leaning on ditching the notification concept as well, simply because if you think about how a real radio works, the song names are displayed as part of the interface and are scrolling on by and but still allowing the user to complete their core tasks of listening to music.

Comment: I agree. Didn't think about it that way, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Not that this idea is your solution, but I have use this for different reasons. You can override the alert. Create a new alert function and see what you can do. It is synchronous, and because of that you can require attention before the next action, and when you override, you cand create more options.

Comment: While I think you have something here, I don't understand the answer, could you provide some kind of example?

Comment: I am already using a [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) and not an alert.